# String comparison in windows batch scripting - what is the unequal operator?

Tags: batch-file, string-comparison

I'm struggling with Windows Shell Scripting.

I found out how to check for equality between strings:

```
if %name%==GEORGE (
   //do something 
)
```

But nowhere have I found how to check for inequality between strings ... is it this?:

```
if %name%<>GEORGE (
   //do something 
)
```

... or this?:

```
if %name%!=GEORGE (
   //do something 
)
```

... or this?:

```
if NOT %name%==GEORGE (
   //do something 
)
```

... or something else?

Comment: Have you read the help when typing `if /?` into a command prompt window? `if not %name%==GEORGE` is going to work...

Comment: `If` with `EQU`, `NEQ`, `LSS`, `LEQ`, `GTR` and `GEQ` is generally used when parsing numbers, whereas the `==` comparison operator always results in a string comparison. If comparing numbers, you'd use `If %number% NEQ 65…`. When comparing strings, you should, where possible, enclose those strings in doublequotes to ensure that spaces and poison characters are included/protected, and should be aware of the case insensitive option. I would therefore recommend that you use `If /I Not "%name%" == "GEORGE"…`

Comment: That last comparison should have worked. Really depends on what is in `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `if /?` from the prompt for a full listing. `neq` is the unequal operator.